# Post an item using react js

Tags: reactjs

My application make a post request to an api. The issue is that the post request does not work properly. 
Now the data from :

```js
const postData = () => {
    postMessageNew({
      first: 1,
      second: 2
    });
  };
```

... riches till :

```js
export const postMessageNew = newMessage => {
  console.log(newMessage);
  return {
    type: POST_MESSAGE,
    newMessage
  };
};
```

So, the data after clicking button, reaches only till above `console.log`, not till post request from `saga` file. What could be the problem? 
And how to fix the code? Why the values don't appear in the code bellow?

```js
function* postNewMessage(newMessage) {
  console.log(newMessage);....
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-franklin-g8x3o?file=/src/App.js:129-219

Comment: @Federkun, could you take a look plaese to my question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up Redux properly, including a reducer, and use the saga middleware to run your saga:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootSaga from "./sagas";

import rootReducer from "./Reducer";
import App from "./App";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Check out a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-khayyam-uy06r?file=/src/App.js

Comment: the code does not work. I get `Expected the reducer to be a function.`, plus the `Reducer` is empty.

Comment: whoops must not have saved. look again

Comment: it works, but if i want to fetch all list of posts after i make this post request, how should i do this?

Comment: You could make your action return a promise, write a new getAllPosts action that fetches all posts, and call the new action after the first promise resolves: postMessageNew().then(() => getAllPosts()). Or you could just chain a second fetch in postNewMessage after the first fetch resolves. I updated the sandbox to include an example of the latter

Comment: I tried to create a fetc action, but if i want to see the result after posting i should to refersh the page, and only after that i can see new post. This is happening even i added a dependance in `useEffect`. What could be the issue?

Comment: That's out of the scope of this question and I can't answer that without seeing your code, if you need that answered as well you should post a new question that includes the code you need fixed.